# How can I make my Google+ posts and comments available to the public communities that I've joined?

Tags: google-plus

Every time I commented on a Google+ post, I noticed that my comments were being ignored and no one seemed to even see my comments. I've made comments on various posts from communities that I've joined, and posted pictures on the page as well, and I never got a single +1 or comment on them. To test whether I was just being ignored, or my posts and comments were not visible to the public I logged into my other Google account and went to the same posts and looked for the comments I made but they were not there at all. I could see the comments of others who wrote before and after me but my own were some how non-existent. Please help me to make my posts and comments visible to everyone. I don't understand, I checked my settings and everything but nothing seems to work.